# Warning: mysql_query() expects parameter 2 to be resource, null given in C:\xampp\htdocs\3s_shop\admin\pembelian_data.php on line 6 error paging:

Tags: javascript, php

This is my form distributor data code.
If I click the button before it would be an error

> Warning: mysql_query() expects parameter 2 to be resource, null given in C:\xampp\htdocs\3s_shop\admin\pembelian_data.php on line 6
>   error paging:

What's wrong in the code?

```
<?php
# UNTUK PAGING (PEMBAGIAN HALAMAN)
$baris = 50;
$hal = isset($_GET['hal']) ? $_GET['hal'] : 0;
$pageSql = "SELECT * FROM pembelian";
$pageQry = mysql_query($pageSql, $koneksidb) or die ("error paging: ".mysql_error());
$jml     = mysql_num_rows($pageQry);
$maksData    = ceil($jml/$baris);
?>
<table width="800" border="0" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="1" class="table-border">
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2" align="right"><h1><b>DATA PEMBELIAN</b></h1></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2" align="right"><a href="?open=Pembelian-Add" target="_self"><img src="../images/btn_add_data.png" height="30" border="0" /></a></td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td colspan="2"><table class="table-list" width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="2">
      <tr>
        <th width="35" align="center" bgcolor="#CCCCCC">No</th>
        <th width="250" bgcolor="#CCCCCC">Nama Reseller</th>
        <th width="100" bgcolor="#CCCCCC">Tanggal Pembelian</th>
        <th width="250" bgcolor="#CCCCCC">Nama Produk</th>
        <th width="150" bgcolor="#CCCCCC">Harga Produk </th>
        <th width="50" bgcolor="#CCCCCC">Jumlah Produk </th>
        <th width="150" bgcolor="#CCCCCC">Total Harga </th>
        <td colspan="2" align="center" bgcolor="#CCCCCC"><strong>Tools</strong></td>
      </tr>
      <?php
    $mySql = "SELECT * FROM pembelian ORDER BY nm_reseller, tgl_pembelian, nama_barang, hrg_barang, qty ASC LIMIT $hal, $baris";
    $myQry = mysql_query($mySql, $koneksidb)  or die ("Query salah : ".mysql_error());
    $nomor = $hal; 
    while ($myData = mysql_fetch_array($myQry)) {
        $nomor++;
        $Kode = $myData['kd_pembelian'];

        // Warna baris data
        if($nomor%2==1) { $warna=""; } else {$warna="#F5F5F5";}
    ?>
      <tr bgcolor="<?php echo $warna; ?>">
        <td align="center"><?php echo $nomor; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $myData['nm_reseller']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $myData['tgl_pembelian']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $myData['nama_barang']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $myData['hrg_barang']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $myData['qty']; ?></td>
        <td width="44" align="center"><a href="?open=Kategori-Edit&Kode=<?php echo $Kode; ?>" target="_self" alt="Edit Data">Edit</a></td>
        <td width="44" align="center"><a href="?open=Kategori-Delete&Kode=<?php echo $Kode; ?>" target="_self" alt="Delete Data" onclick="return confirm('APAKAH ANDA YAKIN INGIN MENGHAPUS DATA PEMBELIAN INI ... ?')">Hapus</a></td>
      </tr>
      <?php } ?>
    </table></td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="selKecil">
    <td><b>Jumlah Data :</b> <?php echo $jml; ?> </td>
    <td align="right"><b>Halaman ke :</b>
        <?php
    for ($h = 1; $h <= $maksData; $h++) {
        $list[$h] = $baris * $h - $baris;
        echo " <a href='?open=Pembelian-Data&hal=$list[$h]'>$h</a> ";
    }
    ?>    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: `$koneksidb`is clearly undefined

Answer (score 0):

I think you are not establishing connection to your database. The second input should be that connection variable. like this:

```
$link = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
$koneksidb = mysql_select_db('databaseName', $link);
$pageSql = "SELECT * FROM pembelian";
$pageQry = mysql_query($pageSql, $koneksidb) or die ("error paging: ".mysql_error());
```

Comment: different apis don't intermix

Comment: as in `mysqli_` connection with `mysql_` after; that doesn't work. The OP is using `mysql_` functions throughout their code.

Comment: I updated my answer and thanks for that as I didn't know about `mysql` not mixing well with `mysqli`